# Spring Batch skipping exceptions not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job consisting of one step, which is the step below. It reads 100 json files to process them and save them to the database in chunks of 25. As different insert statements within chunks can cause ConstraintViolationException, this could be easily resolved by processing them one by one. That's why I thought about using 'faultTolerant' and skipLimit (also tried with retry), hoping when a chunk of 25 items fails, it would retry them one by one to find the faulty one and commit the other 24 DetailApplications. However this is not the case. It just skips the entire chunk of 25 DetailApplications. The end stats are 3 commits, 100 reads, 75 writes and 1 rollback. What did I do wrong here? Or what did I forget?

Step:

```
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepImportDetailsJob")
            .<DataJson, DetailApplication> chunk(25)
            .reader(detailApplicationReader)
            .processor(detailApplicationProcessor)
            .writer(detailApplicationWriter)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipLimit(5)
            .skip(Exception.class)
            .build();
```

Write method:

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends DetailApplication> list) {
    detailApplicationRepository.saveAll(list);
}
```

The list always comes with size 25 (chunk size), while I would expect this to be 1 when 'locating' the problem.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your config. Chunk scanning should work in your case. Can you try to to narrow the skippable exception type to `ConstraintViolationException`? Otherwise please share a minimal project (with an in-memory db) to reproduce the issue and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46630274/9279756). All I had to do to fix the issue, was flushing the entityManager after saving. My write method now looks like this:

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends DetailApplication> list) {
    detailApplicationRepository.saveAll(list);
    entityManager.flush();
}
```